# In Moodle, how to achieve auto continuity between two different activities (Scorm PPT then Quiz) under a topic?

Tags: php, moodle

**Expectation:**
A user opens a scorm (Basic001) view all the slides once the activity ends, the process must be automatically redirected to the second activity (Quiz).

I have created a "Category" under which I have created a "Topic" where I have added an activity (Scorm Package created using zenler) and then followed by another activity (Quiz) under the Topic (refer to the image below). I have also set restrictions and activity completion requirements.

[image: The activities(ScormPPT & Quiz) under a topic]

I'm using Moodle v2.9

How to achieve this method? If not is there any plugin which helps to achieve this or do this can be achieved by modifying Moodle program?

Comment: The user has to exit the SCORM pack, so that completion data or bookmarks are stored in the LMS.  At that point, there's a "goodbye.html" file that's displayed in the window.  Maybe you can put something in here, although it would probably need to be hard coded.

It might be better to try to intercept the mod/scorm/view.php page when it does the redirection after the user has closed the window with "goodbye.html" in it.